# Can you create body parts with Creo Corpus?

Tags: spells, ars-magica-5, ars-magica

Can you create individual body part (such as an arm) with a creo corpus spell?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Corpus covers "human or humanlike bodies and anything which involves those bodies" (*Ars Magica Fifth Edition*, p 129). Creating a disembodied limb would be a level 5 CrCo effect, the same as creating an entire corpse (*AM5e*, p 130). The target parameter would remain Individual, as the Part target parameter only applies when targeting a section of an existing object (*AM5e* pp 112-113).